# Make navbar fixed on page after scrolling down page 300

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar

On my page I've a navbar at the top. What I want to get is I'm writing down:

1. As I said initially I've a navbar at the top (this is fine, no problem with this.
2. As I start to scroll down the page, page content start to go upwards direction which is fine again.
3. Now when I reach to scrolling down the page to 300, the navbar should get fixed to top of page at 300.

How can I do this?

Here's [CodeSandbox](https://b9i0f.csb.app/) link for your reference.

Comment: Here is updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-forked-p4chz).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, these libraries can help you:

- [waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints)
- [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)

Comment: Ali, is this possible to get this done without any third party library? If so kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed navbar on top of page without using any third party library. Just add this `CSS` in your `index.css`.

```
 .header{
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: YogeshYadav, Sorry for writing you late. I thank you for your assistance for updating CodeSandbox and putting solution in comment section too but I didn't want to fix header from the very starting i.e. top to end i.e. bottom. What I wanted to get header appear only after scrolling down the page to 300. And luckily, I achieved this using component(s)-not only using plain css in style.scss. BTW, Thanks again for your support.